# How to create Main Navigation with Product Attribute instead of category menu, like: Brand or Manufacture and product count will be added also?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, menu, navigation, ce-1.9.2.4

I want a navigation menu build with a specific product attribute in magento 1.9.2 and product count will also show there like: Samsung (14) Hyundai (13) Asus (44)

Can any one great help me please and many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in /default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml 
replace this line with this

> ```
> $html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';
> ```

with this

> ```
> $cat_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $child->getID());
> $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id)->getProductCount();
> $html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $child->getBrand().($products_count) .'</a>';
> ```

$child->getBrand() replace Brand with you attribute name

Comment: Thanks Awadi, actually I am using 2columns-left template for my home page and changed the page.xml for showing page items as menu in topMenu and category items as menu in left sidebar. beneath the categories items menu I want to show Shop by Brand menu items where all my products are using Brand attribute.

Comment: In rwd/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml Brand items menu is showing now but didn't found any clues to view products count under each brand. <?php 
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');
 if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
  $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
  
  foreach ($options as $option)
  {
   
      echo '<li style="list-style:none"><a href="'.Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result').'?brand%5B%5D='.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</a></li>';
  }
 } 
?>